# pandas to_csv write some extra lines

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a large `DataFrame` with 1000K+ rows. I work in jupyter notebook, load the data, make some changes and try to save the processed data.

```
new_data = origin_data.apply(func)
news_data.to_csv('path',sep='\t')
```

But when I checked the file saved, I found some extra lines which seem to came from the `origin_data`. But if I load the file with `pd.read_csv`, everything seems right. I checked the rows around the error lines and the type of the columns, there's nothing wrong. I tried some other ways to save the data, like

```
csv.writer.writerows(new_data.values)
```

But the extra lines still exists and I cannot find them in `new_data.values`.

Have anyone ran into  such problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have line breaks `'\n'` in some text columns - they'll be quoted like `"some text ...\n some text"`.

Consider the following demo:

CSV file (4 lines, including header):

```
a,b,c
11,"text
we are still in the same cell...",33
22,aaa,44
```

DataFrame has only two data rows:

```
In [191]: pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\a.csv')
Out[191]:
    a                                         b   c
0  11  text\r\nwe are still in the same cell...  33
1  22                                       aaa  44
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting issue without using apply function as well? Apply function is called twice and have side effect: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6753